# Venn diagram with background images, add links?

Tags: css, hyperlink, hover, background-image, css-selectors

Have created this venn diagram to use as a kind of nav area.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlyCJ.png

When a user hovers over each circle the image changes (same image, minus green overlay and the text). I would like to make each circle clickable, with each circle linked to the appropriate page in the website.

Can't figure out how though.

Here is the HTML & CSS that I've used to create it.

HTML:

```
<div class="buttons">
<div><a class="buttons" href="fashion_design.html"></a></div>`
<div><a href="costume_design.html"> </a></div>
<div><a href="photography.html"></a></div>
<div><a href="artwork.html"></a></div>
</div><!--buttons-->
```

CSS:
    .buttons div {
        width: 390px;
        height: 390px;
        border-radius:200px;
        -moz-border-radius:200px;
        -webkit-border-radius:200px;
        -khtml-border-radius:200px;
        float:left;
        opacity:.9;
        display:block;
}

```
.buttons div:hover {
background-position:0px 400px;
z-index:5;
position:relative;
```

}

```
.buttons div:nth-child(1) {
background-image:url(images/fashion_hover.png);
color: #FFF;
margin-top:60px;
z-index:1;
```

}

```
.buttons div:nth-child(2){
background-image:url(images/costume_double.png);
color: #FFF;
margin-left:-60px;
margin-top:60px;
z-index:2;
```

}

```
.buttons div:nth-child(3){
background-image:url(images/photography_hover.png);
color: #FFF;
margin-top:-60px;
z-index:3;
```

}

```
.buttons div:nth-child(4){
background-image:url(images/artwork_hover.png);
color: #FFF;
margin-left: -60px;
margin-top:-60px;
z-index:4;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not working as there is no text in the anchor so the anchor is effectively not displayed. You could use jquery:

```
$(".buttons div").click(function(){
     window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
     return false;
});
```

Alternatively just use javascript on each div:

```
<div onClick="window.open('http://yahoo.com');">
```

Comment: Tried out the javascript on each, works perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: Is is possible to get the link to navigate to the page directly instead of opening a new window?

Answer (score 0):

Change your CSS such that it targets the anchor tag than just the div

for eg

```
.buttons div{} should be .buttons div a{}
```

See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/3d5Cp/)